# Delete backup directories using RMAN

Tags: oracle, rman

Is there any way RMAN can delete empty backup directories?

Comment: This may help https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2234040

Comment: Also http://logbuffer.wordpress.com/2011/05/30/oracle-how-to-tell-db-about-manually-freed-space-in-fra/

Comment: Don't think it'll delete manually created folders. Just the folders that get created in FRA.

Answer (score 0):

No. rman does not delete directories that it did not create by itself.